# How to bundle/build javascript files when one file expects a global window object

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, rollupjs

I have written a frontend animation in javascript with the logic beeing split across multiple javscript files. I would like to bundle the files together based on ES6 modules, at least the files I have written myself.

Here is the problem:

```
import { Webfont } from "webfontloader";

...

function animate(myText){
    WebFont.load({
        google: { families: ["Indie Flower"]},
        fontactive: function(familyName, fvd){ //This is called once font has been rendered in browser
            display(myText);
        },
    });
}
```

I import the dependent modules, however one module (webfontloader) contains the window object. This is fine when it runs in the browser but when I build and bundle it with npm und rollup.js, it throws the error:

```
   ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

How can I solve this without touching the code of "webfontloader" which is an external library ?

Do I have even two options ?

- option a) to bundle all my files together and leaving the external libraries external. In production, they would be included as separate script tags.
- option b) to bundle all the files together into one file

Comment: Isn't there in the rollup-config globals option?Check rollup.config.js

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/556

Comment: hmm, My attempts didn't work out so far

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `global` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/global) then use `rollup-plugin-inject`(https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-inject) to tell rollup to replace usages of `window` by the one of `global/window`.

```
// rollup.config.js
import inject from 'rollup-plugin-inject'
export default {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        inject({
            include: 'node_modules/webfontloader/**',
            window: 'global/window'
        })
    ]
```